# How can I SELECT DISTINCT rows from two columns from the same table ignoring bidirectional similars?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `flight` as follows:

```
arrive      | depart
-------------------
New York    | London
New York    | Paris
Washington  | Rome
London      | New York
Rome        | Washington
New York    | Washington
New York    | London
Rome        | New York
Washington  | Rome
```

And I would like to produce a distinct / unique output based on the distinct from `depart`/`arrive` and `arrive`/`depart` - but not those that are bidirectionally the same.  Therefore the outcome from above would be:

```
depart      | arrive
______________________
New York    | London
New York    | Paris
Washington  | Rome
New York    | Washington
Rome        | New York
```

Straightforward to get distinct basis `depart`/`arrive`, but can't get any `JOIN`, `UNION` etc. to ignore the bidirectional same (`arrive`/`depart`), but include bidirectional unique.

Pulling hair out, - need help.  Thanks

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: PRIMARY KEY = 'id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery to remove duplicates.

However one thing to keep in mind is that, in order to get a consistent resultset, you need to define a rule to tell which of the two destinations is considered the `depart`, and which is the `arrive`. Since you did not provide a rule, I chose to have the value with lowest alphabetic order as `depart`.

Query:

```
SELECT
    LEAST(depart, arrive) depart,
    GREATEST(depart, arrive) arrive
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.arrive = t.depart AND t1.depart = t.arrive AND t1.depart > t.depart
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d93AtsLamAqV5QEpqynZx6/1)**:

```
| depart   | arrive     |
| -------- | ---------- |
| New York | Paris      |
| London   | New York   |
| Rome     | Washington |
| New York | Washington |
| New York | Rome       |
```

---

One other solution would be to pick the first occurence of the duplicate in the table, using primary key `id`, which, as per the comments, is available in the table:

```
SELECT depart, arrive
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.arrive = t.depart AND t1.depart = t.arrive AND t1.id < t.id
)
```

Comment: Note that this solution can return rows which don't exist (e.g. New York, Rome above)

Comment: @Strawberry : yes, the first solution would do that (but do it in a predicable manner). The second solution doesn't. Really up to the OP to decide how they want this to he handled...

Comment: @Strawberry : both solutions work fine.  Many thanks for taking the time to solve this for me.